# changing from GET to POST jquery ajax call to c#

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services

I was trying to use GET and ran into trouble. Now I am trying to switch to POST to try it out. I switched my jquery statements from

```
Type: GET,
```

to

```
Type: POST,
```

I switched my .asmx code behind to

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod]
public string testGetParametersDynamic(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    string fullName = firstName + lastName;

    return fullName;
}
```

from

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public string testGetParametersDynamic(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    string fullName = firstName + lastName;

    return fullName;
}
```

I am now getting this error:

An attempt was made to call the method \testGetParametersDynamic\u0027 using a GET request

what am I missing?

Comment: Might be a good idea to post the complete code that is making the call in JS.

Comment: @spender: +1; @dan_vitch: you also can check request type using firebug extention for firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following attribute to service

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
```

**EDIT**

Check out the following code.It's working fine

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default5.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default5" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#btnTest").click(function () {
                var firstName = "a";
                var lastName = "b";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: "{firstName:'" + firstName + "',lastName:'" + lastName + "'}",
                    url: "WebService.asmx/testGetParametersDynamic",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (ret) {
                        alert(ret);
                    }


                }

                );
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="button" name="name" value="Call " id="btnTest" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebService.asmx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;


[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public WebService()
    {


    }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public string testGetParametersDynamic(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        string fullName = firstName + lastName;

        return fullName;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to use:

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
```